# What is MultiOutputRegressor and how does it work?

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn

What is [MultiOutputRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html) in scikit-learn and how does it work?
Are they predicting multi-output using a model trained for each target variable?

Answer (score 1):

I read that can work as a trick to make single output regressors like SVR to support multioutput. You can read a little bit more over here
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from the documentation page you linked to:

> This strategy consists of fitting one regressor per target.

and from the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutputregressor):

> Multioutput regression support can be added to any regressor with MultiOutputRegressor. This strategy consists of fitting one regressor per target.
> Since each target is represented by exactly one regressor it is possible to gain knowledge about the target by inspecting its corresponding regressor. As MultiOutputRegressor fits one regressor per target it can not take advantage of correlations between targets.